# How to interpret Rust error E0495 on the lifetimes of a closure and a variable borrowed by the closure

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

I'm trying to understand a lifetime error. I've reduced the code to this short, albeit nonsensical [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=837d9e6409273fb99752a83212bab8a8):

```rust
type Value = Vec<i32>;

type MemberList<'a> = Box<dyn Iterator<Item = &'a i32> + 'a>;

pub fn traverse<'a, F>(input: &'a Value, f: F) -> MemberList<'a>
where
    F: Fn(&'a i32) -> MemberList<'a> + 'a,
{
    Box::new(
        input
            .into_iter()
            .flat_map(move |v| traverse::<'a>(input, &f)),
    )
}
```

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for borrow expression due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/lib.rs:12:54
   |
12 |             .flat_map(move |v| traverse::<'a>(input, &f)),
   |                                                      ^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'_` as defined here...
  --> src/lib.rs:12:23
   |
12 |             .flat_map(move |v| traverse::<'a>(input, &f)),
   |                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...so that closure can access `f`
  --> src/lib.rs:12:54
   |
12 |             .flat_map(move |v| traverse::<'a>(input, &f)),
   |                                                      ^^
note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the lifetime `'a` as defined here...
  --> src/lib.rs:5:17
   |
5  | pub fn traverse<'a, F>(input: &'a Value, f: F) -> MemberList<'a>
   |                 ^^
note: ...so that the type `&F` will meet its required lifetime bounds...
  --> src/lib.rs:12:32
   |
12 |             .flat_map(move |v| traverse::<'a>(input, &f)),
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...that is required by this bound
  --> src/lib.rs:7:40
   |
7  |     F: Fn(&'a i32) -> MemberList<'a> + 'a,
   |                                        ^^
```

This seems to be saying that if the lifetime of the borrow expression `&f` outlived the lifetime of the closure, then the closure wouldn't be able to access `f`. But I would have thought it was the other way round: the borrow expression needs to live at least as long as the closure in order for the closure to access the expression.

How should I interpret these error messages?

Similar questions have been raised before:

- [What does the Rust error code E0495 mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53703181/155423)
- [How do I work around closures causing error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57912253/155423)
- [Rust: error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autoref due to conflicting requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57036513/155423)
- [Rust: error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for autorefdue to conflicting requirements in closure](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60029939/155423)

These are focussed on fixing, rather than questioning the validity of, the error messages.

Comment: The reference to `F` (in `traverse(input, &f)`) does not live for the lifetime `'a`, so you get an error. Accepting `f: &'a F` allows it to compile. Alternatively, you could make `F` `Copy` or `Clone`, passing down owned values.

Comment: Shepmaster can you share a fixed playground link? I was unable to reproduce with your directions.

Comment: Even if you did pass the lifetime checks, your code would create infinite instantiations of `traverse` since you recursively take the reference of one of types: `traverse<F=F>`, `traverse<F=&F>`, `traverse<F=&&F>`, `traverse<F=&&&F>`, etc

Comment: @PitaJ [one](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5b6497de9ac16e31476d0965018e8cb2) and [another](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=854d1b3487efb7738d6f28a5f1f6dec7)

Comment: @kmdreko Yes, that's one of the reasons I described the code as nonsensical. The original involves a bounded recursion into a data structure, but is considerably larger and distracts from the question of this post.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to bstrie who answered on Zulip, it turns out that the error messages have recently been improved and compiling on nightly, as in this [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=2937d9c49b4d47ca03efe7ba15cbf3f7), produces the following messages:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> src/lib.rs:7:48
  |
5 | pub fn traverse<'a, F>(input: &'a Value, f: F) -> MemberList<'a>
  |                 -- lifetime `'a` defined here
6 |   where F: Fn(&'a i32) -> MemberList<'a> + 'a {
7 |   Box::new(input.into_iter().flat_map(move |v| traverse::<'a>(input, &f)))
  |                                       -------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'a`
  |                                       |
  |                                       lifetime `'1` represents this closure's body
  |
  = note: closure implements `FnMut`, so references to captured variables can't escape the closure
```

The experimental Polonius borrow checker on nightly gives even more context to the explanation:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> someguy.rs:7:48
  |
5 | pub fn traverse<'a, F>(input: &'a Value, f: F) -> MemberList<'a>
  |                 -- lifetime `'a` defined here
6 |   where F: Fn(&'a i32) -> MemberList<'a> + 'a {
7 |   Box::new(input.into_iter().flat_map(move |_| traverse::<'a>(input, &f)))
  |                                       -------- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'a`
  |                                       |
  |                                       lifetime `'1` represents this closure's body
  |
  = note: closure implements `FnMut`, so references to captured variables can't escape the closure

error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
 --> someguy.rs:7:48
  |
5 | pub fn traverse<'a, F>(input: &'a Value, f: F) -> MemberList<'a>
  |                                          - variable defined here
6 |   where F: Fn(&'a i32) -> MemberList<'a> + 'a {
7 |   Box::new(input.into_iter().flat_map(move |_| traverse::<'a>(input, &f)))
  |                                              - ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-^
  |                                              | |                      |
  |                                              | |                      variable captured here
  |                                              | returns a reference to a captured variable which escapes the closure body
  |                                              inferred to be a `FnMut` closure
  |
  = note: `FnMut` closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing...
  = note: ...therefore, they cannot allow references to captured variables to escape
```

This answers my question as the error is about a reference to a captured variable escaping the closure which was far from clear in the original messages.